# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, sugarorm

When i was called 
`mBasicActions=BasicActions.findById(BasicActions.class,1);` 
it showing below error.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl
                                                                                           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                                                                                           at com.orm.util.ReflectionUtil.getDomainClass(ReflectionUtil.java:270)
                                                                                           at com.orm.util.ReflectionUtil.getDomainClasses(ReflectionUtil.java:254)
                                                                                           at com.orm.SchemaGenerator.createDatabase(SchemaGenerator.java:37)
                                                                                           at com.orm.SugarDb.onCreate(SugarDb.java:26)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                           at com.orm.SugarDb.getDB(SugarDb.java:36)
                                                                                           at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:189)
                                                                                           at com.orm.SugarRecord.findById(SugarRecord.java:102)
                                                                                           at com.orm.SugarRecord.findById(SugarRecord.java:108)
                                                                                           at a.example.com.LoginPageActivity.onCreate(LoginPageActivity.java:76)
                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

```
 compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: What is your `compileSdkVersion` ?

Comment: updated please check it

Comment: Do you have the android support lib in your dependencies?